# Verify all brackets are properly open/closed

Tags: php

I am trying to write a function that will return true if brackets are closed, for example `{[()]}` and false if brackets are open, for example `) (` . I have problem with writing logic behind it. I have some idea like modulo, but it won't work and I dont know what direction to look in.

```
function test($result) 
{
    if( $result % 2 === 0 ) { 
        return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear precisely what you mean. Show some proper examples of the content of `$result`, and the output (true or false) you'd expect in each case.

Comment: Can you explain your “idea”? What does a modulo check have to do with any brackets being closed or not?

Comment: I downvoted this, because no attempt was made. The given code is so simple, that it's kind of obvious that it's just a fake to prevent the usual "show your code" comments. In my opinion, this is a "write code for me" question.

Comment: @Martijn I downvoted due to lack of clear examples of the data involved.

Comment: @Martijn I find both comments preceding yours as pretty clear about the reason - it's not a clear question. All we have is an assumption we're dealing with a string that contains some brackets.

Comment: A small side note: you don't need an `else` when you're returning. Just place `return false;` after the `if`.

Comment: Personally I think it's an obvious question, I've tried editting it to reflect that. IMO this question is asking how to aproach this, not perse a code question (at least, I didnt answer it as one), but rather looking for an technique to do this.  As beginner you sometimes dont know what you're looking for, just that you're looking :)

Comment: @Martijn It's still just a guess. At no point was it explicitly stated if this is a string containing brackets exclusively or there is perhaps additional content. Potential solutions still depend on the structure of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting by deleting any chars doesn't mach sets  `{}`, `[]` or `()`, I created helped functions `exist` to check if any of these sets exist in the string and also function `replace` to remove them. loop until nothing can be replaced. Finally check if the remaining length of string after deleting all sets is equal to `0`. which means all brackets and parenthesis are properly opened and closed. Otherwise return false.

```php
function exist($c, $s){
    return strpos($s, $c) !== false;
}
function replace($c, $s){
    return str_replace($c, "", $s);
}

function open_closed($str){
    //remove unneeded chars
    $str = preg_replace('/[^\{\}\(\)\[\]]+/', '', $str);
    while(true){
        if(exist('{}', $str))
            $str = replace('{}', $str);
        elseif(exist('[]', $str))
            $str = replace('[]', $str);
        elseif(exist('()', $str))
            $str = replace('()', $str);
        else
            break;//if any of sets doesn't found, Exit the loop.
    }
    return !strlen($str);//or use strlen($str)===0
}
```

```php
$string1 = '[{()[He9.*]{}}]';
/*
[{()[]}]
[{()}]
[{}]
[]

*/
var_dump(open_closed($string1));//true

$string2 = 'abc[({})][({)]99';
/*
[({})][({)]
[()][({)]
[][({)]
[({)]

*/
var_dump(open_closed($string2));//false
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a stack data structure. If you find an opening bracket, push it on the stack. If you find a closing bracket, pop the top element from the stack. If it is not a good one, for example the first bracket is ), and the popped element is [ or the stack is empty, the expression is invalid.

Important: at the end the stack must be empty.

Comment: Important: at the end the stack must be empty.

Comment: PHP arrays can act as simple stack. You even have [array_pop()](https://www.php.net/array_pop) and [array_push()](https://www.php.net/array_push).

Comment: Re: _"Important"_ - probably best to edit this into the answer. No matter how upvoted it gets, a comment can still end up overlooked.

Comment: I have modified the answer, thx for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

A simple, somewhat bruteforce method (and far from the ideal solution). This is more of a beginner level answer:

- Remove all other characters (if present)
- Replace all sets (eg `{}`, `[]` and `()`) untill nothing is replaced
- return wether the result is an empty string (all matched are gone means all closed)

You make a loop, replace all closed sets and then see if it's shorter now. If it is NOT stop the loop. If it is, continue the loop one more round. And when it ends and is empty, you know :)

Examples:

- `[{}]` -> `[]` ->   => true
- `({}[{}])` -> `([])` -> `()` ->   => true
- `{]}` -> `]` => false

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want. Can you help me write the function correctly?

Comment: You can use str_replace with a array. See example #1: https://www.php.net/str_replace

Comment: I've added the logic in my answer, after the bulletlist

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using Stack. So Iterate over the expression string `exp`. If the current character is a open bracket `'(' or '{' or '['` then push it to stack. else if the current character is a closing bracket `')' or '}' or ']'`. then pop from `stack` and see if the popped character is not matching current bracket then *the brackets are not balanced.* lastly check if stack is *empty?* If So *the brackets are balanced.*

```php
function balanced($expr){
    $open_brackets = ["(", "{", "["];
    $stack = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($expr); $i++){
        $current_bracket = $expr[$i];
        if(in_array($current_bracket, $open_brackets))
            array_push($stack, $current_bracket);
        else{
            //stack cannot be empty at this point!
            if (empty($stack)) return false;

            $popped_bracket = array_pop($stack);
            # If current_bracket is not opening bracket, 
            # then it must be closing; Otherwise return false.
            if($popped_bracket === '(' and $current_bracket !== ")" )
                    return false;
            if($popped_bracket === '{' and $current_bracket !== "}" )
                    return false;
            if($popped_bracket === '[' and $current_bracket !== "]" )
                    return false;
        }
    }
    return empty($stack);
}
```

***tests*:**

```php
var_dump(balanced("[()]{}{[()()]()}")); //true
var_dump(balanced("}{")); //false
var_dump(balanced("[{}(){}]")); //true
```